# Compilation time between compiler and exe

Tags: c++

After testing my program with big chunks of data I noticed that when I run my program on my compiler(Codeblocks) it runs slower than when I click the exe in my folder. Is that true?
Also when I click the exe it doesn't tell me the time it took to compile how can I see the time then?

Comment: You can't run a program on a compiler. Do you mean you run your program in your IDE? Do you compile it before you run it?

Comment: I mean when I press F9 on my codeblocks

Comment: That's "Compile & Run". That means you compile it and then run. Of course this takes more time than just run it.

Comment: How much slower is it because I am making a program for a national competition

Comment: If you save the time of how long it took to compile to a text file, your program can input that text file into a `std::string` and output it to `std::cout`.  Unless you really mean C program and not C++, since you have both tags.

Comment: Why do you compile it? Just run it from your IDE.

Comment: I am using C++ now

Comment: At the top you have "Compile", "Run" and "Compile & Run". Compile it once and then run it.

Comment: Is there any difference in time when I run it in my IDE and when i just click the exe file in my folder?

Comment: Not really. Your IDE should do something similar to a double click on the exe file.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your application on in the IDE, it most often includes some other things for debugging purposes. In visual studio, it attaches a debugger and that takes up quite some performance.

When you directly run the executable, such debuggers wont get attached, thus improving the speed.

Another way to improve your executable performance is through compiler optimizations. You can read about them here: https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=3372264

> Also when I click the exe it doesn't tell me the time it took to compile how can I see the time then?

What the compiler does is, it converts your source code into executables/ libraries. Basically if you run the compiler through your source code once, you don't need to do it again and again (which is what interpreted languages do).